# Knockout.js Sort array within Observable Array

Tags: javascript, sorting, knockout.js

I followed this tutorial for creating sortable tables
http://kindohm.com/posts/2013/08/21/knockout-sortable-tables/

It works great for when I have an observablArray whose elements correspond to columns of a table. However, I have an observableArray (rank) whose elements are games (e.g. rank.soccer) which themselves should be tables. So, here is the essence of my code.

```
self.rank = ko.observableArray();

//Then I use publicGet to do an html request and pull json data into the observable array

self.sortBy_soccer_teamName = function(){
        self.rank().soccer.sort(function(a, b){
            if (a.teamName > b.teamName) return 1;
            if (a.teamName < b.teamName) return -1;
            return 0;
        });
    };


<table style="width: 100%">
  <thead>
  <th><a href="#" data-bind="click: sortBy_soccer_placing">Rank</a></th>
  <th><a href="#" data-bind="click: sortBy_soccer_teamName">Team</a></th>
  <th><a href="#" data-bind="click: sortBy_soccer_matchWins">Match Wins</a></th>
  <th><a href="#" data-bind="click: sortBy_soccer_matchLosses">Match Losses</a></th>
  <th><a href="#" data-bind="click: sortBy_soccer_winPercent">Win Percent</a></th>
  <th><a href="#" data-bind="click: sortBy_soccer_gamesBack">Games Back</a></th>

  <tbody data-bind="foreach: rank().soccer">
   <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: placing"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: teamName"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: matchWins"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: matchLosses"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: winPercent"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: gamesBack"></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</thead>
```

The Json looks like:

```
{
  name: "TeamRank"
  soccer: [20]
  0:  {
      teamId: 47
      teamName: "pandas"
      matchWins: 10
      matchLosses: 0
      winPercent: 100
      gamesBack: 0
      }
  -1: {
      ...
      }
  football: [20]
  O:  { 
      ....
  }
}
```

To make the table I do a data-bind foreach rank().soccer
The table shows up fine, but I can't sort the data, the sorting function does nothing to the table, and it's not anything wrong with the html. It's definitely just the sort function.

So. How does someone sort a list within an observableArray?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the html where you do the data-binds, and perhaps an example of the json?

Comment: You specify `self.rank` is an observableArray, but then you access this inside your sortBy fn using `self.rank().soccer`.  Seems inconsistent.  Can you post the structure of the observableArray, possibly a jsFiddle ( or equivalent ) demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding, rank is an observableArray and soccer is an array for each item in rank. And you want to sort soccer.

Before you put json data into the self.rank, create observableArray for each soccer. In that way, Knockout will pick up the change whenever you change the order of soccer and show the result accordingly.

Comment: yes. I ultimately had to make soccer and football and all the oher games into their own observable arays in order to be able to sort them

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
self.rank = ko.observableArray();

self.rank().sort(function(l, r)
{
  return (l.teamName == r.teamName) ? (l.teamName > r.teamName ? 1 : -1) : (l.teamName > r.teamName ? 1 : -1);
});
```